# How to limit 25 words minimum and 75 words maximum in text area?

Tags: c#, validation

I have required field text area. Which is needs at least 25 words  and 75 words maximum allowed. So how to check these in c# for text and validate it.

Comment: What kind of application you are targeting ? ASP.Net *(Web)*, WinForm, WPF ?

Comment: Is this for winforms or wpf?

Comment: The real problem is make the system understanding what is a "word"...

Comment: You need to be clearer on edge cases. Would "asd.tfds" be one word or two? How about "cliff-hanger" or "Born2Die" or, if you're on the web, "something&nbsp;else"? It probably doesn't *really* matter, but clarity would help you choose which answer would best suit and if you're only splitting on spaces that'd be good to know.

Answer (score 2):

You could split the input string by the whitespace character and check the length of the returned array.

```
string[] words = textArea.Text.Split(' ');
if (words.Length >= 25 && words.Length <= 75)
{
    //Validated
} else
{
    //Not validated
}
```

Comment: Don't forget to ignore empties. Double spaces would count as a word in the above code.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

Working code for windows form application for the field myTextBox type of `TextBox`

```
bool IsTextBoxValid()
{
    var wordCount = myTextBox.Text.Split(' ').Length;       
    return (wordCount >= 25 && 75 >= wordCount)
}
```

to see ***pseudo*** version see old revision of answer

Comment: Nope, it's an actual one. Your answer resembles Javascript, whereas the question is tagged `[c#]`. Moreover, the code in your answer is comparing arrays to numbers, which cannot possibly work as you intend.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi You seems right but this is pseudo though, please undownvote. because today is pseudo monday

Comment: Sorry, but pseudo-code like that does not seem very useful, even on pseudo-mondays.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi So what should I do, update answer or delete it, because I like to write time to time pseudo things. By the way did you heard about [oscillation](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/166483)

Comment: @asdf_enel_hak And I aboslultely understand your answer. Better part of it so the OP will learn. Teach a man to fish....

Comment: This calls split twice.

Comment: @VincentHubert I confess that I was bit lazy to write better pseudo code but OP was lazy as well

Comment: @asdf, that's more useful, thank you for your efforts. A hint in passing: you can factorize the last four lines into a single `return` statement.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi updated again. `Je vous remercie pour la coopearation fantastic`

Answer (score 0):

Two different options for counting words from [DotNetPerls.com](http://www.dotnetperls.com/word-count). Adding your limitation should be easy, once you get the count.

```
  /// <summary>
  /// Count words with Regex.
  /// </summary>
  public static int CountWords1(string s) {
     MatchCollection collection = Regex.Matches(s, @"[\S]+");
     return collection.Count;
  }

  /// <summary>
  /// Count word with loop and character tests.
  /// </summary>
  public static int CountWords2(string s) {
     int c = 0;
     for (int i = 1; i < s.Length; i++) {
        if (char.IsWhiteSpace(s[i - 1])) {
           if (char.IsLetterOrDigit(s[i]) || char.IsPunctuation(s[i])) {
              c++;
           }
        }
     }
     if (s.Length > 2) {
        c++;
     }
     return c;
  }
```

Comment: `== true` is unpleasant.